# How to check slow_query_log for the current project I'm working on?

Tags: mysql, mysql-slow-query-log

I've read good articles on enabling and logging `slow_query_log`, tried and it works.

But I would like to understand how to use it in real life scenarios.

I set the slow query log globally like below, which means its applicable to all databases?

```
SET GLOBAL slow_query_log = 'ON';
SET GLOBAL long_query_time = X;
SET GLOBAL slow_query_log_file = '/path/filename';
```

and so forth.....

Now, the real life scenario:

> My PC has multiple projects hosted by wamp server. But now I want to
> check the queries for project A. How do I check which queries in this
> project works slowly, assuming they are using one database only?

How would the `slow_query_log` know that which database I'm checking? Also how the process flows? I mean, once I enabled the `slow_query_log`, do I type the queries written in the project one by one to see which one slowing down?

Or once I enabled `slow_query_log`, I start making all the calls through the system to the database and then later come back and check what has been triggered by `slow_query_log` during the process?

Incidentally, I prefer using CMD to execute the `slow_query_log`

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the file, use one of these to summarize it.  Then study the first few queries.

```
mysqldumpslow -s t

pt-query-digest
```